# Can a question closed as a duplicate automatically link to the dupe?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, closed-questions

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11943/472) was closed as a duplicate; presumably it is considered a dupe of the question linked in the question body.  It won't always be that clear, though.  On English.SE when a question is closed as a dupe, a link to the other question is automatically added to the closed question.  Can we do that here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens here, too. ([e.g.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/kashrus-in-israel)). The automatically-inserted duplicate reference was deleted by Menachem when he edited the question ([Revision 4](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/11943/revisions)) and inserted his own reference to the previous question.

Comment: sorry, next time I'll leave the duplicate information in, as long as the question is closed